# Creating public and private keys for SSH

Tags: ssh-keys, private-key

Used Putty.gen to create Putty private and public keys. On client system \karpov in \Users\xyz.ssh
I have "id_rsa", "id_rsa.ppk", "id_rsa.pub", "known_hosts".

"id_rsa" contents from private Putty file and "id_rsa.pub" from public Putty file.

When I try to run `ssh clientusername@clientsystem@server name`, I get

> "load pubkey "C:\Users\Harmonia12/.ssh/id_rsa" : invalid format thespar@karpov@archon's password.

When I try to type a password, the keyboard is not active. I can't type into the PowerShell window.  Tried `SSH thespar@karpov@archon` and was expecting connecting to server.

What file has "invalid format"? What is the valid format?

What forum should it be posted on? This is the 2nd substack forum where it was not answered.

Comment: `id_rsa` content should be starts with a line of `-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----` followed by lines of Base64 string of equal length except  perhaps the last, and ended with `-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----`, is that your current `id_rsa` content?

Answer (score 1):

At least `id_rsa` has an invalid format. It sounds like it's the same as `id_rsa.ppk`, which is the PuTTY format for a private key and not the OpenSSH format. In PuTTYgen, you need to use "Conversions" -> "Export OpenSSH key" to save it in the OpenSSH format for use as `id_rsa`.

[image]

On the command-line, this still requires PuTTYgen (I don't know of a way to do it with OpenSSH):

```bash
puttygen id_rsa.ppk -o id_rsa -O private-openssh
```

---

Additionally it sounds like `id_rsa.pub` is also in an invalid format (PuTTY's public key format instead of OpenSSH's). To fix this, you need to copy the contents of the "Public key for pasting into OpenSSH authorized_keys file" text field into the file `id_rsa.pub` manually:

[image]

The latter (public key conversion) can also be done using OpenSSH's `ssh-keygen` command-line tool:

```bash
mv id_rsa.pub id_rsa_putty.pub
ssh-keygen -i -f id_rsa_putty.pub > id_rsa.pub
```